# How to always keep focus on hidden input?

Tags: angular, typescript

After initializing this component, the focus should always be on the input field. Even if I click somewhere else, the focus should be set to this element again.

Currently I set the focus in the `ngAfterViewInit` to this corresponding element, however it is not being kept up.

```ts
@ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.tab && this.tab === true) {
      if (this.input && this.input.nativeElement) {
        this.input.nativeElement.focus();
      }
    }

    const isFocused = this.input.nativeElement === document.activeElement;
  }
```

```html
 <input class="element-hidden" 
          type="text" 
          [(ngModel)]="text"
          (keydown.enter)="onEnter($event)"
          #input
          inputmode="none">
```

How can I implement this? I have already tried `autofocus` but this did not work.
Here is a reproduced example on Stackblitz: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pnvc5u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: focus is loosed after you click outside the focus element (blur event), which is normal behaviour, if you want to keep the focus, you have to re focus in the blur event. something like this, look at app.component.html (blur)="focus()"

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4eipv2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Alright! I actually was  trying to avoid the `(blur)` event, but it seems like theres no other way. It is working - thanks alot!